# "in cannot be resolved to a variable" error showing while write this code in Eclipse (maven project using spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I creating some java projects. in this project I find one error when I'm write code in Eclipse IDE. pls help me to correct this ERROR...

**CoronaVirusDataService.java**(in this file error occurred)
package io.covid.coronatracker.services;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CoronaVirusDataService {
    
    private static String VIRUS_DATA_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv";
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void fetchVirusData() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(VIRUS_DATA_URL)).build();
        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(httpResponse.body());
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(**in**);
        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
            String id = record.get("ID");
            String customerNo = record.get("CustomerNo");
            String name = record.get("Name");
        }
    }    

}
```

**CoronaTrackerApplication.java**(this is main file)
package io.covid.coronatracker;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CoronaTrackerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoronaTrackerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exact error and for which line?

Comment: Well ... you haven't declared a variable called `in` anywhere.  What do you expect the compiler to resolve `in` to?

Comment: Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");